# how does Python handle "from __future__ import division"?

Tags: python

I've looked at the [source code for __future__.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/__future__.py) and it makes no sense to me -- how does this actually work, to change the behavior of division?

Comment: My guess would be that `compiler_flag` might signal to the compiler to change division

Comment: interesting... maybe I just don't understand how `import` really works; I thought it evaluated the module in question and then created a module object which could be brought into namespace scope in totality or with an individual property (`from xyz import abc`). But looking at `__future__.py` it seems like if that module gets evaluated, then all of the features should be enabled. How does `from __future__ import XYZ` cherry-pick the creation of objects in `__future__.py` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That module only serves a documentary / introspection purpose; none of the code in it actually *does* anything.

Rather, when Python is compiling a module, it calls [PyFuture_FromAST](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/compile.c#l272) on the module, which checks for `from __future__ import` statements, and assuming they're valid, [sets the appropriate flags](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/future.c#l23) on a `PyFutureFeatures` object. The compiler then goes and [sets those flags in the compiler context](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/compile.c#l279) before going ahead and actually compiling the module.

For comparison, you can see that in Python 3, `__future__.py` is still the same and contains all of the same information, but in `future.c`, [none of the features actually set any flags](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.0/Python/future.c#l23) because all of those features are enabled by default in Python 3.

Comment: Note: all of the line number links are accurate as of the time I wrote this. I couldn't figure out how to get hgweb to link to a specific revision so that they wouldn't go bad in the future. If anyone would like to edit the links to make them more permanent, they should.

Comment: so the Python interpreter actually knows about `from __future__ import xyz` and handles it specially (not the same as `from ordinary_module import xyz`)?

Comment: @JasonS correct. It's like a pragma or compiler directive in other languages.